# Remove object without odd numbering

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried to use "delete" method on 1,2,4 which would left 0..3..5 instead of 0..1..2..3. How do you remove it properly?

[image: http://s22.postimg.org/8zydta9bl/image.png]

Comment: Google for "remove index in array object".

Comment: @torazaburo I think my question has nothing to do with array.

Comment: You yourself specified Array in the title of your question. Then you refer to "removing an index", where index is a notion specific to arrays (if a standard object, it would be called a "key"). Then you show syntax such as `oItem[0]`, which is an access to an array element. All the people that marked your question as a duplicate thought it was about arrays, because they specified a duplicate that is about arrays. The person that answered thought it was about arrays. So, in what way does your question have nothing to do with arrays?

Comment: @torazaburo It seem to have an object contains array and objects in it, please see my update picture in my question.

Comment: Please delete this question and open a new one. This one has already been closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
var index = array.indexOf(oItem[2]);
if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

The [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method changes the content of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/yLhvxv0d/9/)

Comment: This work for removing particular index in objects = {}?